# How to prevent cycle in same Table parent child relation in JPA Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm kind of new to JPA and Hibernate.
I have an Entity called ingredient and each ingredient can consist of one or many other ingredient with a specific quantity, for this I created another Entity which I called subIngredient with an embedded key. My problem is I want to prevent that an ingredient become sub ingredient of one of his sub ingredient or sub sub ... ingredient.

These are all the related entities:

```
@Embeddable
public class SubIngredientKey implements Serializable{


private Long ingredientId;


private Long subIngredientId;
/**
 * @return the ingredientId
 */


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(ingredientId, subIngredientId);
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof SubIngredientKey)) {
        return false;
    }
    SubIngredientKey other = (SubIngredientKey) obj;
    return Objects.equals(ingredientId, other.ingredientId)
            && Objects.equals(subIngredientId, other.subIngredientId);
}

}



@Entity
public class SubIngredient {


@EmbeddedId
private SubIngredientKey embId = new SubIngredientKey();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("ingredientId")
private Ingredient ingredient;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId("subIngredientId")
private Ingredient subIngredient;

private double quantity;

@JsonIgnore
public SubIngredientKey getId() {
    return embId;
}
public void setId(SubIngredientKey id) {
    this.embId = id;
}


@JsonIgnoreProperties({"subIngredients","photo","photoContentType","ingredientType"})
public Ingredient getIngredient() {
    return ingredient;
}
public void setIngredient(Ingredient ingredient) {
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}



@JsonIgnoreProperties({"subIngredients","photo","photoContentType","ingredientType"})
public Ingredient getSubIngredient() {
    return subIngredient;
}
public void setSubIngredient(Ingredient subIngredient) {
    this.subIngredient = subIngredient;
}

public double getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(double quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "subIngredient= " + getSubIngredient().getName() + " , quantity=  " + getQuantity();
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(ingredient,subIngredient);
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof SubIngredient)) {
        return false;
    }
    SubIngredient other = (SubIngredient) obj;
    return Objects.equals(ingredient, other.ingredient) && Objects.equals(subIngredient, other.subIngredient);
}

}



@Entity
public class Ingredient {

@Id
@GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;


@NotNull
@Column(unique=true)
private String name;
private String photoContentType;
@Lob
private byte[] photo;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"photoContentType","photo"})
@ManyToOne
private IngredientType ingredientType;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "embId.ingredientId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<SubIngredient> subIngredients =  new HashSet<SubIngredient>();



public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhotoContentType() {
    return photoContentType;
}



public void setPhotoContentType(String photoContentType) {
    this.photoContentType = photoContentType;
}

public byte[] getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(byte[] photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}


public IngredientType getIngredientType() {
    return this.ingredientType;
}
public void setIngredientType(IngredientType ingredientType) {
    this.ingredientType = ingredientType;
}



public Set<SubIngredient> getSubIngredients() {
    return subIngredients;
}

public void setSubIngredients(Set<SubIngredient> subIngredients) {
    this.subIngredients = subIngredients;
}

public void addSubIngredient(SubIngredient subIngredient) {
    this.subIngredients.add(subIngredient);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
     String subIngsText = "";
     for(var subIngredient:this.subIngredients) {
         subIngsText = subIngsText + ", " +  subIngredient.toString();
     }
    return "{id= "+id+",name=" + name +", ingredients="+subIngsText+"}";
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    
    return Objects.hash(name);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Ingredient)) {
        return false;
    }
    Ingredient other = (Ingredient) obj;
    return Objects.equals(name, other.name);
}
}
```

Comment: Your OneToMany(mappedBy = "embId.ingredientId" definition is not right according to the JPA specification. You should be referencing the ingredient relationship, not the ingredientId mapping in the referenced SubIngredient entity.

Comment: this is simply mean that OneToMany will select the SubIngredient that have embId.ingredientId equal to the actual ingredient

Answer (score 0):

Such a recursive relationship can't be prevented in JPA - it is up to the application logic to prevent it. This is no different from an Employee/Manager relationship; the calls to set a manager (or add subordinates to a manager) must check that the call is valid. The only difference here is you put in an Entity (subIngredient) to represent the ManyToMany nature of an Employee managing many other employees.

In your case, when ever you add a SubIngredient, your object is going to have to scan the graph to make sure it abides by your application rules or throw an exception.

```
public void addSubIngredient(SubIngredient subIngredient) {
    if (subIngredient!=null && !subIngredient.contains(this)) {
      this.subIngredients.add(subIngredient);
      subIngredient.setIngredient(this);
    } else {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }
}
```

SubIngredient contains can recursively check its subIngredient for the specified ingredient, or use some other approach.

I'm not sure why you would use an embedded Id and the @MapsId("ingredientId") approach in your SubIngredient. The class would look better to me as just simply:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SubIngredientKey.class)
public class SubIngredient {


  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Id
  private Ingredient ingredient;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Id
  private Ingredient subIngredient;
}

public class SubIngredientKey {
  private Long ingredient;
  private Long subIngredient;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if hibernate will automaticilly link ingredient id from SubIngredient  class to Long ingredient of SubIngredientKey class. I will try it.

Comment: It is required to as part of the JPA specification. The key property must match the name of the properties defined within the entity, and the key property type for derived IDs must be the ID from the referenced entity.